# Is it possible to create a data type of length one bit in C

Tags: c

Esentially I want to create a data type `uint1_t`. Is that even possible?

I know the size of the bool data type is one byte. But boolean values only need one bit. So does C essentially only use one bit for bool? If yes, then what does it do with the other seven. Using eight bits where one is sufficient seems such a waste of space.

Comment: No, you must use multiples of bytes.

Comment: You can address individual bits, but at the memory level, the smallest possible allocation is a byte.

Comment: How many `uint1_t`s do you want? If you only want 1, you will get at least 8.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It is not really possible to create a type that occupies one bit.  The smallest addressable unit in C is the `char` (which is by definition one byte and usually, but not necessarily, 8 bits long; it might be longer but isn't allowed to be shorter than 8 bits in Standard C).

You can approach it with :

```
typedef _Bool uint1_t;
```

or:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
typedef bool uint1_t;
```

but it will occupy (at least) one byte, even though a Boolean variable only stores the values 0 or 1, `false` or `true`.

You could,  in principle, use a bit-field:

```
typedef struct
{
    unsigned int x : 1;
} uint1_t;
```

but that will also occupy at least one byte (and possibly as many bytes as an `unsigned int`; that's usually 4 bytes) and you'll need to use `.x` to access the value.  The use of bit-fields is problematic (most aspects of them are implementation defined, such as how much space the storage unit that holds it will occupy) — don't use a bit-field.

<sup>*Including amendments suggested by [Drew McGowen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2478565/drew-mcgowen), [Drax](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1147772/drax) and [Fiddling Bits](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2993960/fiddling-bits).*</sup>

Answer (score 7):

Contrary to what some people believe, there **is** a data type of one bit in C99: it's called `_Bool`. You can also declare bitfields of size 1. **The fact that individual bits are not addressable in C does *not* mean that one-bit data types cannot exist.** That argument is basically comparing apples to oranges.

There isn't, however, a type of which the storage size (`sizeof`) is less than one byte.

Comment: You need to distinguish between the storage size of `_Bool` (which won't be less than one byte) and the range of values for the type (which is, indeed, just one bit's worth — 0 or 1, false or true).

Comment: Bits and bytes are size units, you can't say that there is a data type of one bit if its size is one byte, even if you don't use the rest. This is saying that 1 orange is 8 oranges because you did not eat the 7 others.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler that's **exactly** what I'm doing.

Answer (score 4):

No this is not possible, uint8_t is the smallest data type. Within struct you could use bit fields, besides that not possible to have a data type of just 1 bit.

Comment: I would not recommend the use of bit fields though, except when they are really convenient (to forge protocol headers for instance).

Comment: Do note that this doesn't mean you can just do `typedef struct Bool {unsigned value : 1;} Bool;` and expect `Bool` to be one bit large. For me, it's four bytes.

Answer (score 3):

The smallest object you can create has a `sizeof == 1`. That object will be `CHAR_BIT` bits in size, which on almost every platform you'll ever see, will be 8.

So the smallest object you can create is a `int8_t` aka `char`.

You can do things with bitfields to encode many 1 bit numbers into a larger object, but that's not exactly a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 2):

The closest thing you can come to something like that is by using bit fields.  They are set up within a `struct` and each field of the `struct` determines its width.

Example:

```
struct foo
{
  unsigned int bla   :1;  /* this uses only 1 bit */
}
```

This case still 'wastes' the other bits of the `int` but if you had other fields you could effectively use each bit of the `int` to represent a Boolean value

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is "no"; except for bit-fields, all types *must* map to a whole number of bytes (and multiple bit-fields will occupy the same byte if they can all fit).

From the [horse's mouth](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> **6.2.6 Representations of types**
> **6.2.6.1 General**
> 1 The representations of all types are unspecified except as stated in this subclause.
> 2 Except for bit-fields, objects are composed of contiguous sequences of one or more bytes,
> the number, order, and encoding of which are either explicitly specified or
> implementation-defined.
> 3 Values stored in unsigned bit-fields and objects of type unsigned char shall be
> represented using a pure binary notation.<sup>49)</sup>
> 4 Values stored in non-bit-field objects of any other object type consist of *n* × `CHAR_BIT`
> bits, where *n* is the size of an object of that type, in bytes. The value may be copied into
> an object of type `unsigned char [n]` (e.g., by `memcpy`); the resulting set of bytes is
> called the *object representation* of the value. Values stored in bit-fields consist of *m* bits,
> where *m* is the size specified for the bit-field. The object representation is the set of *m*
> bits the bit-field comprises in the addressable storage unit holding it. Two values (other
> than NaNs) with the same object representation compare equal, but values that compare
> equal may have different object representations
>
> ---
>
> <sup>49) A positional representation for integers that uses the binary digits 0 and 1, in which the values
> represented by successive bits are additive, begin with 1, and are multiplied by successive integral
> powers of 2, except perhaps the bit with the highest position. (Adapted from the *American National
> Dictionary for Information Processing Systems*.) A byte contains `CHAR_BIT` bits, and the values of
> type `unsigned char` range from 0 to 2<sup>`CHAR_BIT − 1`</sup>.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can create a one bit variable suppose int a:1;
You can just assign value to it but cannot scanf it.

Answer (score -1):

No.  8 bits is the minimum size for a type.  You can use a bit field to combine multiple "small" elements together if you really needed sub-byte storage.

However this is rarely a big deal.  Machines have lots of memory and it is rarely necessary to worry about this kind of memory waste.

Comment: If `CHAR_BIT > 8`, then 8 bits is not the minimum size.

Comment: @chris, `int8_t` = 8 bits regardless of `CHAR_BIT`

Comment: @AlterMann: Presumably on a system that has `CHAR_BIT > 8`, you would not be able to instantiate a `uint8_t`.

Comment: @AlterMann, `int8_t` is not guaranteed to exist. I can't speak from actual implementations, but I imagine a platform with `CHAR_BIT > 8` would not provide it.

Comment: Note that technically, `uint8_t` is an optional type that is defined only if the CPU supports it.  The must be a `uint_least8_t` type.  Consider a 36-bit CPU; such things used to exist, though I believe they're museum pieces these days.  For such machines, the `char` type was 9 bits, and there wouldn't be a `uint8_t` type.  However, that is pedantry — in practice, the place you run into issues is with DSP chips; on some of those, the minimum type size is 16 bits, so `CHAR_BIT == 16` and there is, again, no `uint8_t`.